How to vertically align child to middle when parent is vertically aligned to top
The parent div is set to 'vertical-align: top;' and the child div is set to 'vertical-align: middle' but the child is still aligning to the top. How do I make the child align to the middle relative to the height of the parent. I don't know the specific height of the elements, so I can't move them based on their height.


#parent {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
} 

#child {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>




Your current code has child overlapping the parent. Do you want to keep that? If so, you can just use position relative in parent and position: absolute and top: 50% in the child to make it start at middle of parent.

I think Flexbox would be more appropriate. You could declare align-items on the parent or align-self on the child element.


#parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1em;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
} 

#child {
  height: 2em;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>




In your code replace display: inline-block with display: flex in #parent & also add align-items: center that's all.

I'm a flexbox enthusiast, and I doubt this is exactly what you wanted (you said in the middle relative parent, which I believe I have done here). Nonetheless, I think it's a lot closer to what you're trying to get at. Play around with this if you'd like:


#parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1em;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
} 

#child {
  position: relative;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-top: 50%;
  height: 2em;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>



